# Creating XML output with merged cells using T-SQL XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the table which should be outputted as XML (HTML) for `dbo.sp_send_dbmail` procedure as HTML body.

The issue is that some output cells should be merged vertically as shown on the picture below. I spent a lot of time but have no idea how to organize the output with these cell merges.

The source table is `#DF_Exceptions`, the table `#DF_ExcFormat` is for the output and could be rebuilt if it's needed.

Will appreciate any advice and help. The SQL code is attached below.

[image]

```
DECLARE @stylesheet NVARCHAR(MAX);
CREATE TABLE #DF_Exceptions (
    ReportDay DATETIME,
    raw_A     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    act_A     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    exc_A     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    diff_A    DECIMAL(19, 2),
    raw_B     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    act_B     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    exc_B     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    diff_B    DECIMAL(19, 2),
    raw_C     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    act_C     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    exc_C     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    diff_C    DECIMAL(19, 2),
    raw_D     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    act_D     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    exc_D     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    diff_D    DECIMAL(19, 2),
    raw_E     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    act_E     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    exc_E     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    diff_E    DECIMAL(19, 2),
    raw_F     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    act_F     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    exc_F     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    diff_F    DECIMAL(19, 2),
    raw_G     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    act_G     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    exc_G     DECIMAL(19, 2),
    diff_G    DECIMAL(19, 2),
    raw_H     INT,
    act_H     INT,
    exc_H     INT,
    diff_H    INT,
    raw_I     INT,
    act_I     INT,
    exc_I     INT,
    diff_I    INT,
    raw_J     INT,
    act_J     INT,
    exc_J     INT,
    diff_J    INT
);
CREATE TABLE #DF_ExcFormat (
    ReportDay VARCHAR(6),
    TxtValue  NVARCHAR(100),
    Total     DECIMAL(19,2),
    Imported  DECIMAL(19,2),
    Excluded  DECIMAL(19,2),
    [Check]   DECIMAL(19,2),
    [Order]   INT
);
INSERT INTO #DF_Exceptions
VALUES('20210510',10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1),
      ('20210511',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

INSERT INTO #DF_ExcFormat (ReportDay, TxtValue, Total, Imported, Excluded, [Check], [Order])
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_A', raw_A, act_A, exc_A, diff_A, 1  FROM #DF_Exceptions
UNION ALL 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_B', raw_B, act_B, exc_B, diff_B, 2  FROM #DF_Exceptions
UNION ALL 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_C', raw_C, act_C, exc_C, diff_C, 3  FROM #DF_Exceptions
UNION ALL 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_D', raw_D, act_D, exc_D, diff_D, 4  FROM #DF_Exceptions
UNION ALL 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_E', raw_E, act_E, exc_E, diff_E, 5  FROM #DF_Exceptions
UNION ALL 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_F', raw_F, act_F, exc_F, diff_F, 6  FROM #DF_Exceptions
UNION ALL 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_G', raw_G, act_G, exc_G, diff_G, 7  FROM #DF_Exceptions
UNION ALL 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_H', raw_H, act_H, exc_H, diff_H, 8  FROM #DF_Exceptions
UNION ALL 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_I', raw_I, act_I, exc_I, diff_I, 9  FROM #DF_Exceptions
UNION ALL 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),ReportDay,7),6),'_J', raw_J, act_J, exc_J, diff_J, 10 FROM #DF_Exceptions

SET @stylesheet = '<html><body><table><tr><th>Day</th><th>Value</th><th>Total</th><th>Imported</th><th>Excluded</th><th>Check</th></tr>'
        + (SELECT
            (SELECT p.ReportDay AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
            (SELECT p.TxtValue                              AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
            (SELECT p.Total                            AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
            (SELECT p.Imported        AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
            (SELECT p.Excluded AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
            (SELECT p.[Check]                        AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        FROM #DF_ExcFormat p
        ORDER BY p.ReportDay, p.[Order]
        FOR XML PATH('tr'))
    + '</table></body></html>'
SELECT @stylesheet;
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Andy what does your desired output look like?

Comment: Like on the left part. But I have only the right output.

Comment: You need add rowspan Attribute into <td> for the month. For this you will need to know the row count of rows that need to be merged. Example code would be: `<td rowspan="10">May 10</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…

```
select 
   case when row_number() over(partition by ReportDay order by [Order]) = 1 then count(*) over(partition by ReportDay) end as 'td/@rowspan',
   case when row_number() over(partition by ReportDay order by [Order]) = 1 then ReportDay end as 'td', '',
   TxtValue as 'td','', -- nulls will break the table format..maybe: isnull(cast(TxtValue/Total..Check as varchar(xyz)), '')..
   Total as 'td','',
   Imported as 'td','',
   Excluded as 'td','',
   [Check] as 'td'
from #DF_ExcFormat
order by ReportDay, [Order]
for xml path('tr')
```